# Wrong values in second array - pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I've started learning C++ and I found some problem with pointers. I'm not sure what did I wrong

```
char *tablica = NULL;
char *ps;
char c;
int i;

cin >> c;

for (i = 0; c != '@'; cin >> c){
    if (!(isdigit(c))){
        ps = new char[i + 1];
        tablica = ps;
        tablica[i] = c;
        cout << tablica[i] << " na i " << i << endl;
        i++;
        delete ps;
    }
}

for (int n = 0; n < i; n++){
    if (islower(tablica[n]))
        cout << char(toupper(tablica[n])) << endl;
    else if (isupper(tablica[n]))
        cout << char(tolower(tablica[n])) << endl;
    else
        cout << tablica[n] << endl;
}

delete [] tablica;
```

It should ask the user to write a single char, and then check if it's not a number (first array) - works fine.
Then the second one should change lower case to upper case, but in here the values are incorrect. I wrote this code without pointers and it worked fine.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Use [`static_cast<char>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Comment: The problem is you already deleted ps (tablica=ps) in first loop; then in second loop, you reference tablica which already been deleted in first loop

Comment: And also, instead of `char *tablica = NULL`, write `char *tablica = nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ps = new char[i + 1]` you make `ps` point to some memory you allocate.

When you do `tablica = ps` you make `tablica` point *to the same memory*. You don't copy the actual memory pointed to by `ps`, only the pointer `ps` is copied.

That means when you next iteration allocate memory again what you read and stored into the memory pointed to by `tablica` (and `ps`) is gone.

In the second loop the memory pointed to by `tablica` doesn't exist anymore, since last in your previous loop did `delete ps` (which is itself an error, as it should be `delete [] ps`). You attempt to dereference memory that no longer is owned by your program.

Unless your exercise is to learn pointers, then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Before using 'std' library, study this url first[new and delete operators in C++ for dynamic memory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-and-delete-operators-in-cpp-for-dynamic-memory/).

Comment: Right... Now I know what's wrong. Thanks. But my task is to use pointers....And I would like to know if I can make it work ;)

Comment: The memory is gone...So I can't use it second time?

Comment: @justyna Either don't delete it, or make a copy first.

Comment: @justyna Why are you allocating a new array each time through the loop? The array is `i+1` elements, but you only store into one of them. Are you trying to make the array contain all the characters that were entered?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying. I don't know what size it will be so I tried to just  increase the size  each time I want to store the element. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the memory object to which the tablica pointer is referring.

Instead of doing

```
tablica = ps;
```

Use

```
tablica = new char[i+1];
```

So that it could create another memory segment for the array to be used later.